# Trigger a quartz job from database and not xml

Tags: java, spring, oracle, quartz-scheduler

How can I trigger a job from oracle database instead of configuring it in an xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a [JDBCJobStore](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09.html).

You can find the DDL-statmenets to create all required tables in the folder `docs` within your [quartz-distribution](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/downloads/).

Comment: So quartz will automatically store my triggers in these tables ? How does it understand what to store where ?

Comment: A quartz Scheduler uses a single JobStore. I.e. it stores/retrieves everything from that unique JobStore.

Comment: The cronexpression and job details config will still be in the xml file right ?

Comment: No, they will be stored in the JobStore (i.e. the oracle database).
But you could still use plugins like [XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/JobInitPlugin.html).